# render :update gives MissingTemplate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get a non-model form_for to reload if the validation fails. The page containing the form (app/views/sites/devices.html.erb) contains the code to load the form as a template

```
<div id="site-device-form">
   <%= render partial: "shared/site_device_form", locals: {site: @site, site_device: @site_device} %>
 </div>
```

and the form then appears inline as a rendered partial:

```
<%= form_for(:site_device, :url => {:controller=>"site_devices", :action=>"create"}) do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <%= f.hidden_field :site_id, :value => site.id %>
    <!-- etc -->
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

so the form is initially instantiated from the SitesController page, but as it creates a SiteDevice, the form calls the SiteDevicesController#create method to create the page.

SiteDevice has some validation code - so what if it fails. I'm trying to get the page to reload, so the form code simply redisplays (we will get the errors shown once the redisplay works)

```
  if @site_device.save
     flash[:notice] = 'SiteDevice was successfully created.'
     format.html { redirect_to(@site_device) }
  else
     #re-render form
     format.html { render(:update) do |page|
                      page[:site-device-form].replace_html partial: 'shared/site_device_form'
                   end  }
  end
```

Based on my understanding, render(:update) should render the block, passing in the page template. But what I get is an ActionView::MissingTemplate error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template site_devices/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
* "/home/ruby/frontier_development/Frontier/app/views"
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here? How do I get the render to :update the div-id based on the partial I have given it

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: What you're showing here is that you do not want to rerender the page, but just execute some js if the save fails? If so, I'm not sure you'll be able to do that inside a format.html{} -- likely need a format.js{} block but then your request would likely have to change to XHR. Might be easier to just re-render the entire page (template) with an instance variable to show the form.

Comment: Hi miked. Thanks for your response. Is it JS I need to render - I thought I just needed to re-render the partial for the form when it failed to validate? The partial template for the form renders the model errors (initially empty) as part of the form display. So if the validation fails, the model errors is now non-empty. So my thought was that I simply re-render the form, which should now appear with the errors showing, so they can be corrected. Is this the wrong way to approach things? XHR: is this not what render (:update) should do (as per p325 of the PragProg Rails book). Thxs, Steve

Comment: Hi steve... I added a solution with what I think may work for you using render :action instead of render :update.

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating an existing record, (not a new record), you want to render the `edit` template instead.

For a new record, you would render the `new` template.

So replace `render(:update)` with `render(:new)` and you should be good to go.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Matenia. Thxs for the response. So if I understand you correctly, render(:update) do |page| passes the update view into a block as local variable page, rather than updating the current view. page, to get it to  So what argument would I use to render to tell it to use the existing view as a basis?  Thxs, Stve

Comment: try just `render` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember and can tell, the render :update is a way to execute a block of script (rjs) and I'm not sure you really want to go that route.  So, based on our comments, I'm assuming you might want to do something like the following to show your div when you re-render the template.

```
<% if @some_flag %>
  <div id="site-device-form">
     <%= render partial: "shared/site_device_form", locals: {site: @site, site_device: @site_device} %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller action, you want to **re-render the action** (which would likely be "new" inside the create and "edit" inside the update):

using the "new" template for create:

```
def create
  ...
  if @site_device.save
     ...
  else
    #set the flag for the view and re-render the template
    format.html { 
       @some_flag = true
       render action: "new"
     }
  end
end
```

using the "edit" template for create:

```
def update
  ...
  if @site_device.update_attributes(...)
     ...
  else
    #set the flag for the view and re-render the template
    format.html { 
       @some_flag = true
       render action: "edit"
     }
  end
end
```

This is just the gist... and it might help you get on the right track (if I've understood your problem correctly).